# how can i put all of my credential into String?

Tags: string, flutter, google-signin

I am using flutter, and i want to make a login function using google, i have succeded in making those function. My issue was, flutter String data type does not fetch the entire credential because the limitation of its data type is about 900 character and the credential character is more than that. i was able to print the entire credential on the terminal but when i want to send the credential to my api it did not get send entirely, i was wondering if there is a way to send the entire credential to my api and what data type should i use to store my credential?

thanks in advance.

Comment: String type definitely doesn't have this limitation, so most probably you're doing something wrong elsewhere.

Comment: would be helpful if you show the code snippet

Comment: I agree with @KirillBubochkin, string does not have a limitation, you can send a Base64 image to the API and will work fine, add you code from the beginning of your login process to the API request so we can help